# Capitalization Java Program

Tags: java

The directions that were given were:
   Write a program that prompts for and accepts a line of text from the user, and then prints it out with every character in lower case except for the characters that are immediately after a space. These characters are to be capitalized.

NOTE: don't split the string

- Accept a string from user
- Turn all characters to lower case
- Go through each character individually and capitalize the characters after the spaces

My Current Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Capitalize
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a line of text:");
    String TextLine = input.next();
    //String FirstLetter = input.next();
    String NewTextLine = " ";
    int Length = TextLine.length();
    System.out.print("The all lower case line of text is: " + TextLine);
    for(int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        char Letter = TextLine.charAt(i);
        System.out.print(Letter);
        if(Letter != ' ') 
        {
            Letter = Character.toLowerCase(TextLine.charAt(i));
        }
        else
        {
            Letter = Character.toUpperCase(TextLine.charAt(i));
        } 
        NewTextLine = NewTextLine + Letter;
        }
        System.out.print("\nThe new text line of text is: " + NewTextLine);
    }
}
```

**The Output Is:**

Enter a line of text: aBc Def GHIJ 
The all lower case line of text is: aBcaBc
The new text line of text is:  abc

This isn't what I want to get as the output. 
I want to take " aBc DeF GHIJ " and get the out put of all lower case " abc def ghij " and the new text line to be " Abc Def Ghij "

Can someone please help me to figure out where I went wrong with my code? And how to fix it.

Comment: in Java, single quotes are for characters, double quotes are for Strings.

Comment: As a side note, please follow the Java coding convention, by using camelCase for the variable names.

Comment: @nhahtdh - An ironic suggestion for a capitalization program ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing a `char` with a literal `String` `" "`:

```
if(Letter != " ")
   char      String
```

Change the whitespace by literal character `' '`.

```
if(Letter != ' ')
```

From [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> Character and String Literals
>
> Always use 'single quotes' for char literals and "double quotes" for String literals.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Letter != " "
```

To

```
Letter != ' '
```

Double quotes are for Strings and single quotes are for Characters.

You could also do:

```
Letter != 040  // Octal
Letter != 32   // Integer
Latter != 0x20 // Hexadecimal
```

These are the [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/) for Space.

Comment: I changed that but now get the error: The all lower case line of text is: aBcException in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at Capitalize.main(Capitalize.java:16)

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.

Comment: Your problem is here:     `for(int i = 0; i < Length; i++ { char Letter = TextLine.charAt(i-1); }` When `i == 0`, you are grabbing `charAt(-1)`.

Comment: Thanks. that makes sense but I am kinda confused on the actual code part. I thought I had the right logic going on but am getting a completely wrong output. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use a boolean flag. I just [whipped this up](http://pastebin.com/rkKarJ3F) a min ago.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've defined Letter as a char somewhere. Using double-quotes (" ") denotes a String. Single quotes (' ' ) denotes a char. So, change `if(Letter != " ")` to `if(Letter != ' ')`

Comment: My problem is that I thought that was what it is but changing that i still get errors in my program. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at Capitalize.main(Capitalize.java:16)

Comment: ` char Letter = TextLine.charAt(i-1)` : On the first iteration, i is 0. So i-1 is -1, which is an invalid index.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize I was trying to start at something that wasn't there. I am kinda confused on the actual code part. I thought I had the right logic going on but am getting a completely wrong output. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a char to a string. A primitive type to an object.

Change your code to 
    if(Letter != ' ')

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, you shouldn't be using `Letter != " "`, but instead, you could use [`Character.isSpaceChar(Letter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar%28char%29) or [`Charater.isWhiteSpace(Letter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29)